# Sql lite gets all data sent to webservice JSon format in android?

Tags: android

I am creating local database I want to send all data sent to web service.

For example product name one column. Lots of product name is there. I want to send it.

& **Product name = briyani,egg,rice**

I got all details from database below i have mention code:

```
public String fetchMyRowid(String column_name)
{
    String query = "select  "+column_name+" From " + TABLErestaurant;

    mCursor =db.rawQuery(query, null);
    StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();
    if (mCursor.moveToNext()) {

        buf.append(mCursor.getString(0));
        String str = buf.toString();
        System.out.println("**************"+str);

    }

   return buf.toString();
 }
    }

   return buf.toString();
 }
```

In class :

```
HashMap<String, String> paramsvalue = new HashMap<String, String>(); paramsvalue.put("product_name", dataBase.fetchMyRowid(DatabaseHelper.columnproductname));
```

But I have some issue. I got only one product name. I need all product name. Can any one suggest solution for this.

Comment: Might have something to do with your use of `fetchMyRowid`

Answer (score 0):

wel come to stackoveflow,

Please check below link in that i have first select all table's recode then i have created one another method for get all columns value by row. after that i have marge all data in to `JSON`. this is idea you have to do similar way...

https://stackoverflow.com/a/10600440/1168654